# With JSdoc How can I make an object type returned dynamically depending of a the parameter?

Tags: javascript, templates, jsdoc

Hi i need to define a type returned dynamically depending of the parameters.

This is my actual code with jsdoc

```js
/**
 * @param {Array<string>} columns
 * @return {Promise<Array<Object>>}
 */
async function getData (columns) {
  const df = await dfd.readCSV('http://localhost:3000/datasets/linear-regression/auto-mpg/auto-mpg.csv')
  return Array.from(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dfd.toJSON(df.loc({ columns: [...columns] })))))
}
```

My actual type is `Object[]` but i need `{"mpg", "horsepower"}[]` the code is `await getData(['mpg', 'horsepower'])`

I have tried to find ways to detect parameters dynamically with templates, I was expecting to return a dynamic object